# Hyperledger Fabric: Proposal has not been endorsed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to commit a transaction on the Blockchain of the Hyperledger Fabric 2.2 after offline signing of the transaction from users private key.
After signing the transaction proposal,I send it to the endorsers for the endorsements and in response i get following endorsements from the endorser peers.

```
[ { version: 1,
    timestamp: null,
    response:
     { status: 200,
       message: '',
       payload:
        <Buffer 7b 22 4f 72 67 4e 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 78 79 7a 31 22 2c 22 64 6f 63 54 79 70 65 22 3a 22 63 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 22 2c 22 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e 22 ... > },
    payload:
     <Buffer 0a 20 ca 1d b7 e3 be aa 49 c8 29 a7 ec 70 22 e8 16 39 42 5a 0f ba e2 d5 3f fd 73 5d 3b 46 fb a0 4b 1f 12 d8 01 0a 64 12 34 0a 0a 5f 6c 69 66 65 63 79 ... >,
    endorsement:
     { endorser:
        <Buffer 0a 07 4f 72 67 31 4d 53 50 12 d9 07 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 4d 49 49 43 71 54 43 43 41 6c ... >,
       signature:
        <Buffer 30 45 02 21 00 aa ca ad 65 19 c4 f7 81 14 d2 dc e4 66 78 37 e7 9e 26 da 42 6a a6 d4 9f 6b 82 63 c5 96 36 3d c2 02 20 4e a7 57 ab 6f a7 9f 6c 7b 08 53 ... > },
    connection:
     { type: 'Endorser',
       name: 'peer0.org1.example.com:7051',
       url: 'grpcs://localhost:7051',
       options: [Object] },
    peer: 'peer0.org1.example.com:7051' },
  { version: 1,
    timestamp: null,
    response:
     { status: 200,
       message: '',
       payload:
        <Buffer 7b 22 4f 72 67 4e 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 78 79 7a 31 22 2c 22 64 6f 63 54 79 70 65 22 3a 22 63 65 72 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 65 22 2c 22 64 6f 6d 61 69 6e 22 ... > },
    payload:
     <Buffer 0a 20 ca 1d b7 e3 be aa 49 c8 29 a7 ec 70 22 e8 16 39 42 5a 0f ba e2 d5 3f fd 73 5d 3b 46 fb a0 4b 1f 12 d8 01 0a 64 12 34 0a 0a 5f 6c 69 66 65 63 79 ... >,
    endorsement:
     { endorser:
        <Buffer 0a 07 4f 72 67 32 4d 53 50 12 d1 07 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 4d 49 49 43 70 54 43 43 41 6b ... >,
       signature:
        <Buffer 30 44 02 20 6e 9c 3f 83 eb a0 45 5b 94 9b 58 be 38 55 8b 00 58 6c 1e c6 8e 65 bd 34 11 4b 8e 4c 76 6c 76 75 02 20 5c 3f c8 ee 14 43 51 a4 07 e8 3a e7 ... > },
    connection:
     { type: 'Endorser',
       name: 'peer0.org2.example.com:9051',
       url: 'grpcs://localhost:9051',
       options: [Object] },
    peer: 'peer0.org2.example.com:9051' } ]
```

But, when i try to build,a required formatted proposal including the endorsements,to send it to the orderer so that orderer network, orders the transaction and sends it to committing peers for commitment on the Blockchain,but it gives following error

```
Failed to submit transaction: Error: Proposal has not been endorsed
```

code to build the proposal for the orderer

```
let commitment = new Commit('pki','mychannel')
let idx = client.newIdentityContext(user.user);
let commit = commitment.build(idx,{endorsement:ProposalResponse})
```

Followed these instructions https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/Proposal.html#build

Any thoughts are appreciated